# What rate is the radius changing for a sphere?

Tags: calculus, related-rates

I just thought of this question and wondered if there was a nice way to solve it.

**Question:** The volume of a sphere is $100$ cubic metres and is losing $2\mathrm m^3/\mathrm s$.
At what rate is the radius changing at $t = 2\mathrm{s}$?

I dont think I have a nice way of solving this, 
but I thought about finding the volume after 2 seconds, which is 100-2x2 = 96 cubic metres. Then the radius, at this time.
Then find the volume at t = 2.00001 seconds, then the new radius at this time.
Then I use: 
(new radius - old radius)/(2.00001 - 2) 
to find the rate of change of the radius at t = 2s.

I believe there are better ways to solve this type of question. Thanks

Comment: It is relatively easy to solve but it's a requirement that you at least show some work or thoughts you have when asking, to prevent the site from being flooded with homework questions, so do you have any ideas at all?

Comment: After being asked to show some ideas or workings, the poster did actually show some workings and an idea to solve the problem which would work, assuming that they know how to convert a volume to a radius. Despite that the downvotes and close votes continued until the post was closed for the lack of context reason, even after adding the required context. I think we should reflect on whether this was fair treatment.

Comment: @SuzuHirose I removed my comment, downvote, and also voted to reopen the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your methodology should produce an approximately correct result, but in practice most mathematicians use calculus to solve this type of problem.

Call the volume V and the time from the beginning of deflation $t=0$ then we have the rate of change of volume
$$
{dV\over dt}=-2
$$
Now $V=\frac43\pi r^3$ where $r$ is the radius, so ${dV\over dr}=4\pi r^2$. The rate of change of the radius with time, ${dr\over dt}$, can be got from $${dr\over dt}={dV\over dt}/{dV\over dr}=-{1\over2\pi r^2}.$$ At $t=2$ seconds V=96 so calculate $r=\sqrt[3]{3 V/4\pi}$ (notice that is a cube root, use the $x^y$ button with $y=1/3$ on your calculator) and insert that into the above equation.

That should produce about the same result as your suggested methodology, so as a check why not try the above out, and try your method out, and see if you get the same result both ways.

Comment: Thanks, I understood your method. Tried it and it was close to my approximation.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.